# Select today's (since midnight) timestamps only

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime, timestamp, postgresql-8.4

I have a server with PostgreSQL 8.4 which is being rebooted every night at 01:00 (don't ask) and need to get a list of connected users (i.e. their timestamps are `u.login > u.logout`):

```
SELECT u.login, u.id, u.first_name
FROM pref_users u
WHERE u.login > u.logout and 
      u.login > now() - interval '24 hour'
ORDER BY u.login;

           login            |           id   | first_name
----------------------------+----------------+-------------
 2012-03-14 09:27:33.41645  | OK171511218029 | Alice
 2012-03-14 09:51:46.387244 | OK448670789462 | Bob
 2012-03-14 09:52:36.738625 | OK5088512947   | Sergej
```

But comparing `u.login > now()-interval '24 hour'` also delivers the users before the last 01:00, which is bad, esp. in the mornings.

Is there any efficient way to **get the logins since the last 01:00** without doing string acrobatics with `to_char()`?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

This should be 1) correct and 2) as fast as possible:

```sql
SELECT u.login, u.id, u.first_name
FROM   pref_users u
WHERE  u.login >= now()::date + interval '1h'
AND    u.login > u.logout
ORDER  BY u.login;
```

As there are no future timestamps in your table (I assume), you need no upper bound.

Some equivalent expressions:

```
SELECT localtimestamp::date     + interval '1h'
     , current_date             + interval '1h'
     , date_trunc('day', now()) + interval '1h'
     , now()::date              + interval '1h'
```

`now()::date` used to perform slightly faster than [`CURRENT_DATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) in older versions, but that's not true any more in modern Postgres. But either is still faster than [`LOCALTIMESTAMP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) in Postgres 14 for some reason.

`date_trunc('day', now()) + interval '1h'` slightly differs in that it returns `timestamptz`. But it is coerced to `timestamp` according to the `timezone` setting of the current session in comparison to the `timestamp` column `login`, doing effectively the same.

See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

---

To return rows for the previous day instead of returning nothing when issued between 00:00 and 01:00 local time, use instead:

```
WHERE  u.login >= (LOCALTIMESTAMP - interval '1h')::date + interval '1h'
```

Comment: Thank you. Does a cast from date to timestamp cost anything?

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: But `date_trunc('day', now())` might cost even more, don't you think?

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: nice work and thanks for the effort, +1 from me. But out of curiosity, using the expression in question in a `WHERE` clause should be evaluated only once per query, right?

Comment: This looks like it will return no results between 0.00 and 1.00 local time- that's fine if we are looking for today's results since 1.00, but OP states he wants the results since that last 1.00.

Comment: @cmc: I added a fix for the corner case. Updated across the board while being at it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Awesome! And clever, I'd used a CASE, which is always ugly, didn't test performance though.

Answer (score 21):

```
select * from termin where DATE(dateTimeField) = '2015-11-17'
```

This works well for me!

Answer (score 20):

```
select * from termin where DATE(dateTimeField) >= CURRENT_DATE AND DATE(dateTimeField) < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 DAY'
```

This works for me - it selects ALL rows with todays Date.

Comment: Why not just `select * from termin where DATE(dateTimeField) = CURRENT_DATE`?

Answer (score 15):

An easy way of getting only time stamps for the current day since 01:00 is to filter with 
`CURRENT_DATE + interval '1 hour'`

So your query should look like this:

```
SELECT u.login, u.id, u.first_name
FROM pref_users u
WHERE u.login > u.logout AND
      u.login > CURRENT_DATE + interval '1 hour'
ORDER BY u.login;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

```
where 
    u.login > u.logout 
    and     
    date_trunc('day', u.login) = date_trunc('day', now()) 
    and 
    date_trunc('hour', u.login) >= 1
```

Comment: If `u.login` is string, just add `::date` after it.

Answer (score 0):

All answers so far are incorrect because they give the wrong answer between 0.00 and 1.00. So if you happen to run the query in that time period you get no results. Based on @ErwinBrandstetter's answer, what you want is this:

```
WHERE u.login > u.logout
AND u.login >= CASE WHEN NOW()::time < '1:00'::time THEN NOW()::date - INTERVAL '23 HOUR' ELSE NOW()::date + INTERVAL '1 HOUR' END;
```

I would love to do without the conditional but found no way to.

Edit: @ErwinBrandstetter did do it without a conditional, leaving this here for completeness.