# Can you delete old entries from a table index?

Tags: sql, database

I made a reminder application that heavily writes and reads records with future datetimes, but less on records with past datetimes. These reminders are indexed by `remind_at`, so a million of records means a million on the index, but speeds up checking records that must be reminded in the next hour.

```
| uuid    | user_id | text         | remind_at           | ... | ... | ... |
| ------- | ------- | ------------ | ------------------- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45c1... | 23      | Buy paint    | 2019-01-01 20:00:00 | ... | ... | ... |
| 23f1... | 924     | Pick up car  | 2019-02-01 20:00:00 | ... | ... | ... |
| 2d84... | 650     | Call mom     | 2020-03-01 20:00:00 | ... | ... | ... |
| 3f1a... | 81      | Get shoes    | 2020-04-01 20:00:00 | ... | ... | ... |
```

The problem is performance. Once the database grows big, retrieving any record becomes relatively slow.

I'm trying to check what RDBMS offer a full or semi automated way allow better performance retrieving future datetimes, since past datetimes are rarely retrieved or checked.

A neat solution that I don't know if exist would be to **instruct the RDBM to prune old entries from the index**. I don't know if any RDBM allows that, but in [PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744931/add-datetime-constraint-to-a-postgresql-multi-column-partial-index), [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2017), and [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html) there is a way to use a "partial index", but what would happen if I **recreate an index on a table with millions of records?

Some solutions that didn't fit the bill:

- Horizontal scaling: It would replicate the same problem, `(n)` number of times.
- Vertical scaling: still doesn't fix the problem.
- Sharding: Could be, since every instance would hold a part of the database, but the app will have to handle the "sharding key".
- Two databases: Okay, one fast and other slow. Moving old entries to the "slow instance" (toaster) would be done manually. Also, the app would have to be heavily modified to check both databases since it doesn't know where it is initially. *Logic increases heavily*.

Anyway, the whole point is to make future (or the closest) records to remind snappier on retrieval while disregarding the performance to retrieve older entries.

Comment: Scheduled job to move records to a history table every N hours?

Comment: Or just look at partitioning

Comment: This question is unanswerable without knowing the queries that become slower and their execution plans. The speed of accessing rows with an index scan does not depend much on the size of the index.

Comment: Show us the query, `SHOW CREATE TABLE, and `EXPLAIN SELECT ..`