# Comparing two dates in a SQL request

Tags: php, postgresql, datetime

I am a beginner in PHP and Javascript, so I'm struggling to compare two dates in a `SELECT` request like this:

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM shortcode WHERE invalid_from_shortcode < Date()";
$result = pg_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
    echo pg_last_error();
    exit();
}
?>
```

I'm trying to select only the 'shortcodes' where the [invalid_from_shortcode] column is inferior from the current date.
I don't know how to get the current date and whether the structure is correct.

Comment: WHat has javascript got to do with this question

Comment: What kind of field is `invalid_from_shortcode` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> ...
> $sql = "SELECT * FROM shortcode WHERE invalid_from_shortcode < Date()"; 
> ...
> ```

A PHP functions like `Date()` is not visible in the SQL string. Either pass a value or use an equivalent Postgres function, like [@pr1nc3 already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50021111/939860).

However, while you do not disclose the actual data type of `invalid_from_shortcode` it's unclear whether `now()` can serve as equivalent function. It returns the current `timestamp with time zone`, which is meaningfully different from the current date - effectively equivalent to the current `timestamptz` truncated to 00:00 according to the current `timezone` setting. You might need [`CURRENT_DATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) (same as `now()::date`) instead. Related:

- [Select today's (since midnight) timestamps only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716868/select-todays-since-midnight-timestamps-only/9717125#9717125)

Aside: Unlike two other answers suggested, there is no <strike>`CURDATE()`</strike> in Postgres. That probably confusing MySQL with Postgres.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
  require 'db.php';
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM shortcode WHERE invalid_from_shortcode < NOW()";
    $result = pg_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
        echo pg_last_error();
        exit();
    }
 ?>
```

`Date()` is a php function. in Mysql/PostgreSQL you must use `NOW()`

Comment: seems that runs on PostgreSQL (pg_query...)

Comment: you are right. Thankfully they use the same function name.

Comment: You're welcome, glad i helped. Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use NOW() not DATE().

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for CURDATE() .

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM shortcode WHERE DATE(invalid_from_shortcode) < CURDATE()";
```

Comment: There is no `CURDATE()` in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
NOW()      Returns the current date and time
```

Comment: There is no `CURDATE()` in Postgres.

Comment: I know. I didnt see `pg_query($sql)` :p

Answer (score 0):

You should be using NOW() function instead of date() and you need to convert the date in a suitable format [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) you can visit this link for converting the date format